# Solve linear system using iterative method with solveWithGuess and a sparse b vector in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am currently using Eigen 3.4.0 to solve linear systems of equations `Ax=b` where both `A` and `b` are sparse. I am using the BiCGSTAB method, which is iterative, like so:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A;
Eigen::SparseVector<double> b;

Eigen::BiCGSTAB<SparseMat, Eigen::IncompleteLUT<double>> solver;
solver.compute(A);
Eigen::SparseVector<double> x = solver.solve(b).eval();
```

Turns out, in some cases I may have an initial guess that I can give to the solver (also a sparse vector). So my first instinct was to do this:

```
Eigen::SparseVector<double> x0;
Eigen::BiCGSTAB<SparseMat, Eigen::IncompleteLUT<double>> solver;
solver.compute(A);
Eigen::SparseVector<double> x = solver.solveWithGuess(b, x0).eval();
```

But I get the error `No matching member function for call to 'solveWithGuess'`. Alright, why? So I tried this code:

```
Eigen::SparseVector<double> sv;
VectorXd dv;

solver.solveWithGuess(sv, dv); // ERROR
solver.solveWithGuess(dv, sv); // OK
solver.solveWithGuess(sv, sv); // ERROR
solver.solveWithGuess(dv, dv); // OK
```

Apparently, even though I can call `solve` with a sparse `b` vector, I must call `solveWithGuess` with a dense `b` vector. Why? And is my only option really to convert `b` into a dense vector before calling `solveWithGuess`? That's very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

List of public functions from `Eigen` documentation for `Eigen::BiCGSTAB`:

```
Inherited from Eigen::IterativeSolverBase<BiCGSTAB<_MatrixType, _Preconditioner>>
const SolveWithGuess<BiCGSTAB<_MatrixType, _Preconditioner>, Rhs, Guess> solveWithGuess(const MatrixBase<Rhs> &b, const Guess &x0) const

Inherited from Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Derived>
template<typename Rhs>
const Solve<Derived, Rhs> solve(const MatrixBase<Rhs> &b) const
 
template<typename Rhs>
const Solve<Derived, Rhs> solve(const SparseMatrixBase<Rhs> &b) const
```

As you can see there are two implementations of `solve` one that takes sparse arguments and one that takes dense ones.

As for `solveWithGuess` there is only one implementation that takes dense arguments.

That's because `solve` comes from the top, most general class `SparseSolverBase`.
The `solveWithGuess` comes from `IterativeSolverBase` that derives from `SparseSolverBase` and `IterativeSolverBase` doesn't work on sparse arguments.

So this function just isn't in the library, but I don't know the reason why it's not present.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I noticed Eigen is missing an overload of `solveWithGuess` that takes `SparseMatrixBase`. My question was why it's missing and if there's another option besides converting to a dense vector.

Comment: The solution of a sparse linear system is very unlikely to be sparse itself. Converting a sparse guess to a dense vector once should in general be cheaper than doing sparse operations on vectors which are actually dense.

Comment: @chtz That's actually not the point. It's the `b` vector that cannot be sparse, for some reason, not the guess vector. This does not make sense to me.